# How to set maximum date in uidatepickerview as today 23:59?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uidatepicker

How do I set maximum date in `UIDatepickerView` as today 23:59pm.
I tried like this

```
        datePicker.maximumDate = [NSDate date];
```

But it is not working.
How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `NSDateComponents` to create that particular date.

Comment: You need to create a new `NSDate`for todays date with as time 23:59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
  NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

NSString *currentDateStr = [[df stringFromDate:currentDate] stringByAppendingString:@" 23:59"];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

NSDate *maxDate = [df dateFromString:currentDateStr];

NSLog(@"max date : %@",maxDate);

NSLog(@"max date str : %@",[df stringFromDate:maxDate]);

yourDatePicker.maximumDate = maxDate;
```

**Update :**

Another approach using `NSDateComponents` as suggested by @droppy,

```
  NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];
NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];
NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];
dateComponents.hour = 23;
dateComponents.minute = 59;

NSLog(@"%ld : %ld : %ld",(long)day,(long)month,(long)year);

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *resultDate = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

NSLog(@"result date : %@",resultDate);
NSLog(@"result date string : %@",[df stringFromDate:resultDate]);

yourDatePicker.maximumDate = resultDate;
```

Comment: What a horrible way to do it.

Comment: @Droppy : you can suggest another approaches if you have any better idea!!

Comment: Yeah using `NSDateComponents`.

Comment: @Droppy : yeah, can achieve by `NSDateComponents` also. Updated answer accordingly!